# array.filter doesn't seem to be working at all?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

The HTML for the javascript that's going to follow

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

The javascript that's working is

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
  return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = ages.filter(checkAdult);
}
```

No problem with it. But this code below doesn't seem to work.

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = ages.filter(function(checkAdult){
    checkAdult > 18;
  });
}
```

I want to know why it doesn't work and how can I make it work?

Comment: You forgot the `return` statement... `return checkAdult > 18;`

Comment: Oh, Thank You!!! I've been troubling myself for like a couple of hours. Thank You Very Much.

Comment: You're welcome. This is an example where languages with strong type systems are so beneficial. Dart and TypeScript are two that compile to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You return nothing in the function. Write an arrow function or use `return` keyword:

```
let ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = ages.filter(checkAdult => checkAdult > 18);
}
```

Comment: Thank You!! I've been troubling myself for like a couple of hours

Answer (score 0):

You are missing return in callback function.

As to documentation on: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the callback function should return a value that coerces to true to keep the element, or to false otherwise.

So your code should look like this

```
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText = ages.filter(function(checkAdult){
    return checkAdult > 18;
  });
```